# How to tell if the output of the "find" command is empty?

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to return an exit status of 0 if the output is empty and 1 otherwise:

```
find /this/is/a/path/ -name core.*
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62433568/3878948

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you say you want it to return a particular number, are you referring to the exit status? If so:

```
[[ -z `find /this/is/a/path/ -name core.*` ]]
```

And since you only care about a yes/no response, you may want to change your find to this:

```
[[ -z `find /this/is/a/path/ -name core.* -print -quit` ]]
```

which will stop after the first core file found. Without that, if the root directory is large, the find could take a while.

Comment: This will return 0 if the output is nonempty, not if it is empty.

Comment: Oops. Logic was reversed. Corrected above. Alex is correct with `-z`

Answer (score 6):

Here's my version. :)

```
[ -z "$(find /this/is/a/path/ -name 'core.*')" ] && true
```

Edited for brevity:

```
[ -z "$(find /this/is/a/path/ -name 'core.*')" ]
```

Comment: Heh, I was thinking, "To set the exit status." But yeah, duh, the test already does that, it's totally unnecessary, good catch.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably many variants, but this is one:

```
test $(find /this/is/a/path/ -name core.* | wc -c) -eq 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this

```sh
find /this/is/a/path/ -name 'core.*' | read
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this:

```
if test $(find $path -name value | wc -c) -eq 0
    then
     echo "has no value"
     exit
else
   echo "perfect !!!"
fi
```